# Difficulty getting python regular expression to work

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to set up a regular expression for python to match any non-whitespace character one or more times, then as long as it's prepended with a comma, any whitespace character zero or more times.

What I have been attempting to use so far:

```
([+-])(\S(?:,\s*)*)+
```

I have a string like: `"+foo,   bar -baz" or "+foo,bar -baz"`, etc. and want to get two matches with the groups `("+", "foo,bar")` and `("-", "baz")`

Comment: I want to be able to match something like: `"+foo, bar -baz" but also "+foo,bar -baz"`, etc. you mean match the entire string? Can you give an example of the string that you are looking at and what you want to be matched?

Comment: Sure thing. Added an edit

Comment: Would you like to preserve the whitespaces in your match?

Comment: @Ashwin I'd prefer it if they were stripped somehow with the regex, which is why i was trying to use a non-capture group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('([+-])(\w, ]+)')
>>> p.findall('+foo,   bar -baz')
[('+', 'foo,   bar '), ('-', 'baz')]
>>> p.findall('+foo,bar -baz')
[('+', 'foo,bar '), ('-', 'baz')]
```

If you dont want to preserve the whitespaces, try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('([+-])(\w,]+)')
>>> tempString = '+foo,   bar -baz'
>>> p.findall(tempString.replace(' ', ''))
[('+', 'foo,bar'), ('-', 'baz')]
```

In this case, the tempString is not modified, but you remove the spaces and then try the match

Comment: The only issue is that it's not going to be passed strictly \w word characters

Comment: You can add other characters using \W or, be specific, or just use .*? which is .* (match all) ? (less greedy)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
>>> regex = r"([+-])(\S+,\s*\S*|\S+$)"
>>> re.findall(regex, "+foo,   bar -baz")
[('+', 'foo,   bar'), ('-', 'baz')]

>>> re.findall(regex, "+foo,bar -baz")
[('+', 'foo,bar'), ('-', 'baz')]
```

To deal with matching the `-baz` at the end of the string, it was easier to split the match after the `[+-]` into two separate cases with `|`.

**Edit**: if commas are not always present, the regex `r"([+-])(\S+(?:,\s*\S*)|\S+$)"` might be more suitable.

Comment: Great attempt but there isn't necessarily always a comma.
I'm trying to use it to parse a command to add and remove entries to a whitelist/blacklist

Comment: Ah OK. Would `r"([+-])(\S+(?:,\s*\S*)|\S+$)"` be any better? If not, some more examples might help to get closer to a solution.

Comment: That only seems to match up to two groups of entries
but with a combination of this and  @Ashwin 's answer, I was able to come up with a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To match any number of whitespace character followed by **,**:

```
[^\s]+,
```

Then in your code you could write its:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'[^\s]+,', re.MULTILINE)
>>> s = "+foo, bar -baz"
>>> [x.replace(',', '') for x in p.findall(s)]
['+foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think what you are looking for is this:

```
p = re.compile(r'^[+-]?[^\s,]+(?:, ?[+-]?[^\s,]+)*$')
```

Comment: Close but not quite. Maybe now that I've edited the question you'll be able to understand what I'm trying to get?

Comment: @G.Chi: Your requirements stay always unclear. What should return: `foo, bar, baz`?

Comment: re.findall should return two matches of groups `("+", "foo,bar") and ("-", "baz")`